# Many to Many restriction of one side

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables

```
user
id | etc |

game
id | etc 

user_game
user_id | game_id
```

I want to create a situation where `n` users couldn't create another game if and only if they already have a game between those `n` users.

so for example, assume we have `user_ids: 1,2` and they're both playing in `game_id 1`, they can't create another game between them, they could however create a new game if `user_id 3` joins the game.

Is it possible to query for such thing, if so - how could I go about it? tried playing with queries, joins, selects and where's for far too long :)

EDIT: the end result should be that I query for severel users, and see if they're elgible to play together (ie. no records were found of those `n` users playing together).

Comment: What do you want as a result ? In my understanding, you want to display a list of couple of users compatible, ie who are not playing together; Is it right?

Comment: I think you need another table to related the 2 or more users to a game

Comment: I think the logic belongs to the application more than to the db. So you can retrieve a list of users compatible for a particular user but you can't retrieve all the eligibility for several users

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have a table with the list of proposed users.  I'll call it ProposedUsers.  You can do the following to find any game_id that has those users:

```
select game_id
from user_game ug join
     ProposedUsers pu
     on ug.user_id = pu.user_id
group by game_id
having count(distinct ug.user_id) = (select count(distinct user_id) from ProposedUsers)
```

Your question is a bit unclear as to whether the match to an existing game is exact (no other users on the game) or not.  The above handles the subset case.  The exact match would be:

```
select game_id
from user_game ug left outer join
     ProposedUsers pu
     on ug.user_id = pu.user_id
group by game_id
having count(distinct ug.user_id) = (select count(distinct user_id) from ProposedUsers)
```